# Is there an easy way to rename multiple files (along a naming convention) through command prompt?

Tags: windows, bash, command-line-interface

I have hundreds of files in a folder, currently with the format: (#######-ccc)_(1), where # represents an integer and c represents a letter. I need them all to be renamed #######_ccc_1. Is there an easy way to do this via command prompt, or does it have to be done manually? I understand the mv function can only take one at a time.

ls output looks like this:

```
04/15/2021  06:39 PM    <DIR>          ..
04/15/2021  06:39 PM            34,436 (1101110-PMC)_(1).jpg
04/15/2021  06:39 PM            24,868 (1101111-PMC)_(1).jpg
04/15/2021  06:39 PM            24,842 (1102690-MARB)_(1).jpg
04/15/2021  06:39 PM            48,451 (1118150-DIVE).jpg
```

Comment: You mean the filename contains parenthesis? what does an `ls` command output look like (please shorten to a few files)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way using just `bash`:

```sh
# Make sure extended pattern matching operators are enabled
# (Should already be on in interactive shell sessions)
# +(pattern) matches one or more occurences of pattern
shopt -s extglob

for file in \(+([[:digit:]])-+([[:alpha:]])\)_\(1\); do
    # Remove all parens and change first dash to underscore.
    newfile="${file//[()]}"
    mv "$file" "${newfile/-/_}"
done
```

Or using `prename` (Usually installed as part of `perl`):

```sh
prename 's/[()]//g; s/-/_/' \(+([[:digit:]])-+([[:alpha:]])\)_\(1\)
```

Comment: The error, "File unexpected at this time" comes up. I put exactly what you had above

Comment: @BryceWilkings Both work fine for me after making some test files (`touch "(123456-abc)_(1)"` etc.)

Comment: That doesn't look like a bash error message...

Comment: Well I am using command line on windows

Comment: ... then why in the world is this question tagged linux?

Comment: Though it'll work the same on a Windows port of bash.